# reference ruby class without module name

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in ruby to load a module containing many classes and be able to access these classes without prefixing them with the module name?  Consider foo.rb and bar.rb:

foo.rb:

```
require 'bar'
bar = BarModule::Bar.new()
```

bar.rb

```
module BarModule
  class Bar
  end
end
```

Basically I'd like the ability, from foo.rb, to refer to the class "Bar" without specifying its module every time I reference it.  In java terms, I'm looking for something akin to:

```
import BarModule.*;
```

Anything like that exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modules can be mixed in to one another. To use BarModule as a mixin, you want to `include BarModule`.

Comment: Worth noting you still must `require` the file that contains `BarModule`, which acts as an effective copy and paste of the contents.